# Datatables serverside Select WHERE from Additional tables

Tags: php, datatable, datatables, server-side

I have serverside like this.

```
$qteamwork = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tw_rcpa_users WHERE leader='$selectuname'");
$rowteam = mysql_fetch_array($qteamwork);
$teamname = $rowteam['nama'];

$table = 'rcpa_click_report';     
$primaryKey = 'click_id';

$columns = array(
  array( 'db' => 'click_username',  'dt' =>'click_username' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_landercode','dt' =>'click_landercode' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_cid',       'dt' =>'click_cid' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_offer',     'dt' =>'click_offer' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_revenue',   'dt' =>'click_revenue' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_country',   'dt' =>'click_country' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_ip',        'dt' =>'click_ip' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_device',    'dt' =>'click_device' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_os',        'dt' =>'click_os' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_browser',   'dt' =>'click_browser' ),
  array( 'db' => 'click_visittime', 'dt' =>'click_visittime' ),
);
// SQL server connection information    

$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, "click_username = '$teamname'")
);
```

But WHERE clause not working correctly, this code only show array number one..

Now I want to show all data. How to resolve this? Thank You..

Comment: is any error given?

Comment: **Stop** using deprected `mysql_*` API.Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead

Comment: **STOP** complaining about people using certain pieces of software! :) `mysql_*` is only deprecated **if** you are using a PHP +5.5.x and many people are happy with less, for those the "original mysql API" as it now is called is as good as ever ...

Comment: Deprecated or not, it is recommended by the PHP manual itself to drop its use in favor of `mysqli_*` (included since PHP 5, released a _long_ time ago) or PDO for MySQL 4.1.3 (released a _long_ time ago) or later: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php